# How can I format this VBA RegExp?

Tags: regex, vba

Currently taking the names from the names of some .xlsx files the having the following formats:

- IT-Name LastName -VP Name LastName - Report - Month Year
- IT-Name LastName - Report - Month Year
- Name LastName-Name LastName - Month Year
- Name LastName - Report - Month Year

and so on...
I can easily separate the names from the - report - month year and -vp parts and put them into a LastName, Name format.

The problem I'm currently having is that some of the names will have dashes in them. For example something along the lines Bob Smith-Jones.

I am new to using VBA and RegEx and this is the pattern I'm using to separate the names once they're in a Name LastName[ ]?[-][ ]?Name LastName format.

```
'                      Name         LastName       -        Name            LastName
objRegEx2.Pattern = "([a-zA-Z]*)[ ]([a-zA-Z]*)[ ]?[-]?[ ]?(([a-zA-Z]*)[ ]([a-zA-Z]*))?"
newFile = objRegEx2.Replace(newFile, "$2, $1, $5, $4")
'To remove ", , " when there is only one name
newFile = Replace(newFile, ", , ", "")
```

Is there any way to get a name with the Bob Smith-Jones format into a Smith-Jones, Bob format? Currently they end up in a Smith, BobJones format

Comment: Do you mean you have a names like `Bob Smith` but also `Bob Smith-Jones`? And you want, `Smith, Bob` and also `Smith-Jones, Bob` ? It would be better if you add a real (or fake) example filename that isn't matched by your regex.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to happen

Comment: The dash is your field separator (bad idea, imho)? Are you sure you don't have `Anna-Maria Smith` or even `Anna-Maria Smith-Jones` in your data? How can you tell a field separator from a hyphen? Only if you can precisely define this you can implement a solution - no matter if you use RegEx or any other way (personally, I would give the `split`-command a try rather that playing around with RegEx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off - you can use:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)[ ]([a-zA-Z\-]+)( \- )([a-zA-Z]+)[ ]([a-zA-Z\-]+)
```

Note you need to escape the `-` in the 'LastName' part with a `\` because as you can see `-` is a special regex character.

To get the `,`s between the names I updated the replace clause to `"$2, $1 $3 $5, $4"`.

If you want to match names like `Billy-Bob Smith` as well as `Bob Smith-Jones` you can put the additional `\-` in the first-name parts of the pattern like:

```
([a-zA-Z\-]+)[ ]([a-zA-Z\-]+)( \- )([a-zA-Z\-]+)[ ]([a-zA-Z\-]+)
```

Test code (in Excel):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "([a-zA-Z\-]+)[ ]([a-zA-Z\-]+)( \- )([a-zA-Z\-]+)[ ]([a-zA-Z\-]+)"
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegex.Pattern = strPattern

    strInput = "Billy-Bob Smith - Terry Smith-Jones - July 2017"
    strOutput = objRegex.Replace(strInput, "$2, $1 $3 $5, $4")

    Debug.Print strOutput

End Sub
```

Gives:

```
Smith, Billy-Bob  -  Smith-Jones, Terry - July 2017
```

Comment: Has a bit of tweaking to do on my end but this is working, thanks.